# How to obtain Android Device key in AIR with Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, token, google-cloud-messaging, ane

I am trying to make a push notification in my game using GCM through AWS.
I have bought this ANE: http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/comment-page-2/
But I cannot get the token in my device. 
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe AIR does not have a built-in function to get any device id, because of various platforms. You should use some kind of extension, like Distriqt's [Application](http://distriqt.com/product/air-native-extensions/application) ANE.